# markdown to json using gulp

Tags: json, gulp, markdown

i want to convert a readme file to json using "gulp-markdown-to-json". When i run gulp from the command line i get 'TypeError: md2json.parse is not a function'.

here are my dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-markdown-to-json": "^1.0.3",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  }
```

gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var md2json = require('gulp-markdown-to-json');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('test.md')
        .pipe(md2json.parse())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
})
```

Comment: Try the [markdown-to-json](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/markdown-to-json/1.0.0) Python package, if you are ok with using other languages,

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing two things up here:

- [gulp-markdown-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-markdown-to-json)
- [md-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-json)

According to the [#usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-markdown-to-json#usage) of gulp-markdown-to-json:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const markdownToJSON = require('gulp-markdown-to-json');
const marked = require('marked');

marked.setOptions({
  pedantic: true,
  smartypants: true
});

gulp.task('markdown', () => {
  gulp.src('./content/**/*.md')
    .pipe(markdownToJSON(marked))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```

There's no `md2json.parse()` in the above example.

There are a few markdown parsers available, but you have to try them to see which one (with proper configs) fits your needs best.

The output from the document indicates the `marked` parser outputs html in `body`, and this may not be your desired result:

```
{
  "slug": "bushwick-artisan",
  "title": "Wes Anderson pop-up Bushwick artisan",
  "layout": "centered",
  "body": "<h2 id="yolo">YOLO</h2>\n<p>Chia quinoa meh, you probably haven't heard of them sartorial Holowaychuk pickled post-ironic. Plaid ugh vegan, Sixpoint 8-bit sartorial artisan semiotics put a bird on it Mission bicycle rights Club-Mate vinyl.</p>",
  "updatedAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```